# How to dynamically control tooltip display in a JavaFX application

Tags: javafx, tooltip, javafx-8

I am looking for a way to dynamically control the tooltip display in a JavaFX application, based on some global property. Say suppose in my application there are 1000 nodes which have tooltip installed. I have a Boolean property to set the tooltips turn on/off. How can I achieve this in a more feasible way? 
Just to let you know, I am aware of tooltip install/uninstall features. I don't want to do this for all the 1000 nodes every time user toggles the setting property.

My initial thought is to extend the Tooltip control and set some event filter for "onShowing" which consumes the event if the setting property is false. But this is not stopping the tooltip to display. The tooltip is displayed even if I consume the event.

Alternatively I tried setting the event dispatcher as well. But that too didn't worked. Below is the code that I tried to work on.

Any help regarding this is much appreciated.

```
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventDispatcher;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

public class CustomTooltip extends Tooltip {

    public static boolean SHOW_TOOLTIP = false;

    public CustomTooltip(String txt){
        super(txt);

        // Approach #1
        addEventFilter(WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWING, e->{
            if (!SHOW_TOOLTIP) {
                e.consume();
            }
        });

        // Approach #2
        //setEventDispatcher();
    }

    private void setEventDispatcher() {
        final EventDispatcher oed = getEventDispatcher();
        final EventDispatcher ned = (event, tail) -> {
            Event r = null;
            if (!SHOW_TOOLTIP) {
                event.consume();
            } else{
                r = oed.dispatchEvent(event, tail);
            }
            return r;
        };
        setEventDispatcher(ned);
    }
}
```

Below is the complete example/demo that demonstrates my requirement.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventDispatcher;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

public class TooltipDisableDemo extends Application {
    public static boolean SHOW_TOOLTIP = false;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene sc = new Scene(root, 700, 700);
        stage.setScene(sc);
        stage.setTitle("Tooltips Disable Demo");
        stage.show();

        CheckBox showToolTip = new CheckBox("Enable tooltip displaying");
        showToolTip.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, old, show) -> SHOW_TOOLTIP = show);
        showToolTip.setSelected(true);

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            Tab tab = new Tab("Tab " + i);
            tab.setClosable(false);
            FlowPane fp = new FlowPane();
            fp.setPadding(new Insets(10));
            fp.setHgap(15);
            fp.setVgap(15);
            for (int j = 1; j < 51; j++) {
                StackPane sp = new StackPane();
                sp.setStyle("-fx-background-color: gray");
                sp.setPadding(new Insets(0,5,0,5));
                sp.getChildren().add(new Label("SP T"+i+" - "+j));
                Tooltip.install(sp, new CustomTooltip("This is stack pane " + j + " in Tab " + i));

                Button btn = new Button("Button T"+i+" - "+j);
                btn.setTooltip(new CustomTooltip("This is button " + j + " in Tab " + i));
                fp.getChildren().addAll(sp, btn);
            }
            tab.setContent(fp);
            tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
        }
        VBox.setVgrow(tabPane, Priority.ALWAYS);

        VBox vb = new VBox();
        vb.setSpacing(10);
        vb.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        vb.getChildren().addAll(showToolTip,tabPane);
        root.getChildren().add(vb);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    /**
     * Custom tooltip implementation.
     */
    class CustomTooltip extends Tooltip {

        public CustomTooltip(String txt){
            super(txt);

            // Approach #1
            addEventFilter(WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWING, e->{
                if (!SHOW_TOOLTIP) {
                    e.consume();
                }
            });

            // Approach #2
            //setEventDispatcher();
        }

        private void setEventDispatcher() {
            final EventDispatcher oed = getEventDispatcher();
            final EventDispatcher ned = (event, tail) -> {
                Event r = null;
                if (!SHOW_TOOLTIP) {
                    event.consume();
                } else{
                    r = oed.dispatchEvent(event, tail);
                }
                return r;
            };
            setEventDispatcher(ned);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to turn off/on __1000__ Tooltips at once? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your requirement for 2 :).

Comment: @kleopatra, added the example code to the question.

Comment: thanks for the example :) So your flag should control whether tooltips can be shown or not, right? Then why is the [answer by jai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52031572/203657)  unsuitable (except your not wanting to install/uninstall - why not)? Just want to understand :)

Comment: hmm ... not entirely certain why/if we should expect the filter to prevent the showing on consume (it's not documented anywhere). And faintly remember to have experienced differences on event handling of a window vs. controls (where filters on input events f.i. do block the event to reach the control). Anyway: as you do have the custom tooltip, instead of installing a filter you can override its `show(windox, x, y)` method to do nothing, aka: return if the flag is false

Comment: @kleopatra, overriding show method did the trick :). Thanks for the solution. This is the most simple approach I can think off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the final working demo as per kleopatra's suggestion. I am overriding the protected method show() and conditionally calling the super method  to show the tooltip.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TooltipDisableDemo extends Application {
    public static boolean SHOW_TOOLTIP = false;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene sc = new Scene(root, 700, 700);
        stage.setScene(sc);
        stage.setTitle("Tooltips Disable Demo");
        stage.show();

        CheckBox showToolTip = new CheckBox("Enable tooltip displaying");
        showToolTip.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, old, show) -> SHOW_TOOLTIP = show);
        showToolTip.setSelected(true);

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            Tab tab = new Tab("Tab " + i);
            tab.setClosable(false);
            FlowPane fp = new FlowPane();
            fp.setPadding(new Insets(10));
            fp.setHgap(15);
            fp.setVgap(15);
            for (int j = 1; j < 51; j++) {
                StackPane sp = new StackPane();
                sp.setStyle("-fx-background-color: gray");
                sp.setPadding(new Insets(0, 5, 0, 5));
                sp.getChildren().add(new Label("SP T" + i + " - " + j));
                Tooltip.install(sp, new CustomTooltip("This is stack pane " + j + " in Tab " + i));

                Button btn = new Button("Button T" + i + " - " + j);
                btn.setTooltip(new CustomTooltip("This is button " + j + " in Tab " + i));
                fp.getChildren().addAll(sp, btn);
            }
            tab.setContent(fp);
            tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
        }
        VBox.setVgrow(tabPane, Priority.ALWAYS);

        VBox vb = new VBox();
        vb.setSpacing(10);
        vb.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        vb.getChildren().addAll(showToolTip, tabPane);
        root.getChildren().add(vb);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    /**
     * Custom tooltip implementation.
     */
    class CustomTooltip extends Tooltip {
        public CustomTooltip() {
            super();
        }

        public CustomTooltip(String txt) {
            super(txt);
        }

        @Override
        protected void show() {
            if (SHOW_TOOLTIP) {
                super.show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can always do a binding, if the `Tooltip` is to be installed on a control (i.e. you can't use this for a `Pane`, for example).

```
public final class ToolTipManager {
    public ToolTipManager INSTANCE; // Some singleton implementation
    public final ReadOnlyBooleanProperty enabledProperty() { return enabled.getReadOnlyProperty(); }

   // ...
}

public class MyController {
    @FXML private Button button;
    private Tooltip myTooltip;

    @FXML private void initialize() {
        button.tooltipProperty().bind(
            Bindings.when(ToolTipManager.INSTANCE.enabledProperty())
                    .then(myTooltip)
                    .otherwise((Tooltip)null));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution. Your solution indeed worked :). But as kleopatra solution of overriding the show() method is more easy and straight forward I am sticking with that solution.